# Finding rotation angle of the image for camera in Android

Tags: android

I am grabbing images from an Android camera using `onPreviewFrame.` The images do not always come out vertical. Looks like it is based on:

1. The orientation of the camera with respect to the device as returned by `CameraInfo.orientation`. I guess this value is always fixed for a given device.
2. At what angle the user is holding the camera as returned by `Display.getRotation().`
3. Whether the camera is front-facing or rear-facing.
4. Screen orientation as returned by `Configuration.orientation.`

I am wondering if anyone has a function that computes the angle one would need to rotate the obtained image. Regards.

Comment: If you're not required to support SDK < 21 you could use the new API at `android.hardware.camera2` which seems to provide the camera orientation, cf [CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#SENSOR_ORIENTATION).

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that the bitmap saved on disk always has the same orientation, but depending on the device's orientation at the capture time, an EXIF parameter "orientation" will be set. Applications must use this information to rotate the image properly before displaying it, or saving it to the correct orientation once and for all.

Use the [ExifInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html) class to get this information from a `File`.

It's a bit messy but you can see how I use this in one of my app [here](https://github.com/exoplatform/exo-android/blob/b2d0155a857fcbbe5ac473a1ec6c8ccc63738f93/app/src/main/java/org/exoplatform/tool/DocumentUtils.java#L310-L388) :

- `getExifOrientationAngleFromFile(String filePath)` to get the orientation as an int
- `rotateBitmapByAngle(Bitmap source, int angle)` to rotate the original bitmap to the correct orientation
- `rotateBitmapToNormal(String filePath, Bitmap source)` as the entry point for the 2 other methods

HTH.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am not sure if this would work in my case. I am getting the frames and feeding them off to a remote viewer. With this method, looks like I might have to first store a dummy file. Secondly, for each preview frame, if I have to call the outlined logic, I am thinking my frame rate would drop tremendously.

Comment: Yes indeed it requires a file on disk to work, so it's not suitable for a direct preview.